# IE7 shows links improperly

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, hyperlink

This site doesn't work properly in IE7:
http://www.remleehospitalfoundation.org
It worked fine in Chrome and IE8 supposedly.  This isn't my site.

HTML consists of standard relative links:

```
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

In IE 7's status bar, the above link appears as:

```
http://./contact
```

Why is IE7 the only browser affected, and how can this be fixed?
Again, this isn't my site but was asked to find out what's up.

Thanks for any help you can offer.  I have never seen anything like this in my entire career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPdate: I was talking out of my bum.

Look at the source and you get your answer `(<base href="./")`

```
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
    <link href="templates/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print" /> 
    <title>Dr. R.E.M. Lee Hospital Foundation - Board of Directors</title> 
    <base href="./" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfade.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/lightbox.css" media="screen" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script> 
</head>
```